# Mono experimantal packages and apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, mono

I have a slight problem trying to get the mono experimental 3.0.6 installed on ubuntu. I am quite unexperienced with ubuntu and apt-get so bear with me please. I come from this link: http://www.meebey.net/posts/mono_3.0_preview_debian_ubuntu_packages/

Where it says to add this to the `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://debian.meebey.net/experimental/mono /
```

Which I did, then ran `apt-get update`. But when I try `apt-get install mono-complete` the installer complains that I have unsatisfied dependencies, all mentioning version 2.10.8.

Now I can see in the repository that the dependencies listed are version 3.0.6 so I don't know why apt-get is complaining and what should I need to do to let it get the packages all from that repo. Thanks to anyone that can shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're running a 32-bit Ubuntu. This repository only has 64-bit packages. Search for "mono-complete" in http://debian.meebey.net/experimental/mono/Packages and you'll see:

```
Package: mono-complete
Source: mono
Version: 3.0.6+dfsg-1~exp1~pre1
Architecture: amd64              <--- 64-bit!
```

Comment: On my way to install a 64bit ubuntu and I will let you know if it works :) thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Ok, I trust this is the problem... I cannot get a 64bit VM on here since the VT in the BIOS is disabled and there is no chance the IT admin will give me the BIOS password to change it... at least not in the next month :(

Comment: I would open the cabinet and reset the BIOS. :)